# HSLayers WPS GUI problem

Tags: geoserver, wps

I have a GeoServer running, I have made a process that simply returns the requested tiff.
Now here's the deal : when I send my request from the integrated WPS demo in GeoServer, the GUI gives me a list of available maps to choose from. 
However, when I try the same thing with my (working) HSLayers client (a simple HTML page with an embedded js WPS client), the GUI asks me for an URL and I have no list of maps.
I would prefer having them shown.

Additionnaly, if I take any random process, the GUI will work fine. If I switch between processes, everything works fine (updating input fields, etc.). But once I switch to my AddGeoTIFF process, the GUI generator bugs and doesn't switch anymore (I have to reload the page).

Is this due to a small error in the HSLayers client or is it a problem in the prototyping of my process ?

Here's my process' code :

```
@DescribeProcess(title = "AddGeoTIFF", description = "Returns a GeoTIFF\n")
public class AddGeoTIFF implements GSProcess {

private static final CoverageProcessor PROCESSOR = CoverageProcessor.getInstance();

@DescribeResult(name = "result", description = "The resulting GeoTIFF")
public GridCoverage2D execute(
        @DescribeParameter(name = "coverage", description = "The GeoTIFF you wish to obtain") GridCoverage2D coverageA,
        ProgressListener progressListener) throws ProcessException {
            return (GridCoverage2D) coverageA;
    }
}
```

I am not good with Java and based it on an existing process, so there might be some horrors.

I have been looking for the cause of the issue, and it is (what I believe to be) a parsing error. The (on the fly) GUI generator's part which troubles me can be found in `[HSLayers install file]\source\HSLayers\WPSClient\complexField.js`, on lines 77 to 82. If someone experienced could have a look at it, It'd help.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but HSLayers-WPS implementation is no longer maintained, can't help you with that.